# Scipy loadmat memory leak

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-leaks, scipy, garbage-collection

I am using scipy loadmat to load some data from .mat files. However, I've noticed that it occupies a lot of the RAM memory ~1Gb per .mat file. I know that .mat files are compressed etc. but that still looked to me like a lot of memory so I've tried to investigate why is that happening.

I've made a simple code snippet and noticed that when not loading the data my app takes ~25Mb of RAM and when loading the data it takes about 1Gb of RAM memory. Moreover, that memory is not free'd when I've exit the function which calls scipy loadmat. To make the example code even more dummy, I tried not even to take the results from the scipy loadmat, but just to call that function, but even then 1Gb of RAM memory still stays occupied.

I've also tried to explicitly call garbage collector, but it free'd about ~100Mb and still ~900Mb stays occupied. Why is that? Why the memory used by my process is not the ~25Mb when returning from loadData function? Loadmat should load data from .mat file into the memory, but since noone is referencing it, why it is not free'd?

```py
import scipy.io
import os

import gc
import time

file_names = ["data.mat"]


def loadData():
    input_files_no = len(file_names)

    for i in range(input_files_no):
        scipy.io.loadmat(os.path.join("..", "data", file_names[i]), struct_as_record=False, squeeze_me=True, mat_dtype=True)

    return


def main():
    loadData()

    a = 0
    print("passed")
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
        a = a + 1
        gc.collect()


main()
```