# Scikit-learn LinReg triggers Scipy 'MatReadWarning'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy

The code I have is short and concise, but I cannot due to proprietary reasons share the .mat files associated.  I have tried to create .mat files using matlab in a similar fashion, but the newly created mat files do not cause the warning.

Warning:

> packages\scipy\io\matlab_mio.py:227: MatReadWarning: Duplicate
> variable name "None" in stream - replacing previous with new Consider
> mio5.varmats_from_mat to split file into single variable files
> matfile_dict = MR.get_variables(variable_names)

There is no 'None' variable name.
I've read several different SO answers, and wonder if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56456945/scipy-loadmat-memory-leak,) post about memory leaks is related.  Anyway, curious if others have seen this before.

I wonder if it's how the data is allocated in memory by the underlying libraries.

```
import scipy.io as sio
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression as LR
import numpy as np
import time

def linreg(x,y):
    model = LR().fit(x,y)
    r = model.score(x,y)
    fitx = [min(x),max(x)]
    fity = model.predict(fitx)
    
    return r, fitx, fity


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    
    fname = 'file{}.mat'
    for i in range(5):
        print("Loop {}".format(i))
        mat = sio.matlab.loadmat(fname.format(i))
        
        print("Mat Loaded")
        
        x = mat['x'].tolist()[0]
        y = mat['y'].tolist()[0]
        
        
        lx = np.array(x).reshape(-1,1)
        ly = np.array(y).reshape(-1,1)
           
        
        r, fx, fy = linreg(lx,ly)
        print("sklearn Called")
        #time.sleep(1)
```

Here are some results that are interesting.

If I comment out `r, fx, fy = linreg(lx,ly)`, the scipy MatReadWarning does not appear.  It only appears if a call to sklearn is done.

if `time.sleep(1)` is called, I get error message like this for all loops

- Loop n
- Mat Loaded
- Sklearn Called
- Warning Msg

If I comment out the sleep call I get more randomness

- Loop n
- Mat Loaded
- SKLearn Called
- Loop n+1
- Mat Loaded
- SKLearn Called
- Loop n+2
- Mat Loaded
- SKLearn Called
- Mat Warning 1
- Mat Warning 2
- Mat Warning 3

Why would the call into sklearn impact scipy mat read, why doesn't the error trigger on the load, and why is this error message actually telling me to use a [deprecated](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/io/matlab/mio5.py) method?

scikit-learn              1.2.2           py310hd77b12b_1
scipy                     1.10.1          py310hb9afe5d_0

I will see if I can create a spoof mat to make the example complete.  Until then, I welcome any insights.

Comment: What's the size of individual `lx,ly`?  Could you load all 5 in one loop, and do the `linreg` in another?

Comment: What does `mat['x']` load?  I'm wondering why you are doing the `tolist()[0]`, followed by the `np.aray(...).reshape`.  Can't you just do something like `mat['x'][0,:].None`?  Not that I expect this to affect the warning.

Comment: You might experiment with   `mat = sio.matlab.loadmat(fname.format(i), variable_names=('x','y'))`

Comment: I removed the reasons for the tolist and back tot he array thing.  There is another .csv load and I have to do some scipy interpolations.  I narrowed the problem down to this.  If I cut those out, nothing happens.  I forgot to remove them.  Those were in my short test.  
The original size of lx and ly were biggish (30x2048).  Good questions, let me do some more testing with the matlab load.  I thought about the size of the mats slowing down garbage collection but I could not see anything when playing with the gc debug tools.  I'll follow up if I find anything good out, will spoof larger mats

Comment: I no idea why other operations would mess with the `loadmat`.  The reason I suggested the `variable_names` parameter is that `loadmat` seemed to be complaining about variable names that it had gotten with a quick read of the .mat file.  I haven't dug into the `loadmat` code much, since all the examples I've tried work ok.